# PE file read one section in c

Tags: c, portable-executable

I just read one section in PE file. I have output like this:

```
Section Info (1 of 6)
---------------------
Section Header name :               .text
ActualSize of code or data :        0x49937
Virtual Address(RVA) :              0x1000
Size of raw data (rounded to FA) :  0x49a00
Pointer to Raw Data :               0x400
Pointer to Relocations :            0
Pointer to Line numbers :           0
Number of relocations :             0
Number of line numbers :            0
Characteristics :                   Contains executable code, Readable,

Section Info (2 of 6)
---------------------
Section Header name :               .rdata
ActualSize of code or data :        0x1ed60
Virtual Address(RVA) :              0x4b000
Size of raw data (rounded to FA) :  0x1ee00
Pointer to Raw Data :               0x49e00
Pointer to Relocations :            0
Pointer to Line numbers :           0
Number of relocations :             0
Number of line numbers :            0
Characteristics :                   Contains initialized data, Readable,
```

I just want to read executable sections. For example, how can read .text section?

Comment: I think I do not get your question. You say that you already did read the file. If you only want to know the info from the text section, why is starting at `.text` and ending after the line with "Characteristics" not the answer? Do you ask about reading as a human? Do you ask about programming something to read? Probably the latter. But I do not get the problem you encounter. Maybe because you do not describe it.

Comment: @Yunnosch I just read the section information. like this is x section and x's info. But I do not read actual .text section and I just want to know how can I read

Comment: Look at the info _your_ program prints: `Pointer to Raw Data :  0x400` I'm sure you have some documentation at hand that describes what this entry means. -- Anyway, please [edit] your question and add what exactly you need to know to read the executable sections.

Comment: @thebusybee should I read from PointerToRawData to PointerToRawData +ActualSize ?
or to PointerToRawData + Size of raw data? I could not figure it out.

Comment: Well, you could look with a hex file viewer into the file and see how the bytes you find match with the output of, for example, the disassembly output of objdump. You might need to understand that "pointer" here means the offset in the file.

Comment: @thebusybee I think I should the from PointerToRawData+Size of raw data.  the content of this .text field is in pointer to raw data to PointerToRawData + Size of raw data.

Comment: I think this 'PointerToRawData' is the offset from the beginning of the file. Am I right?

Comment: Try and check the result. ;-) The fascinating  thing on software is the ability to write virtual infinite number of test programs. Find joy in experimenting. You will learn a lot.

Comment: how I know is it true or not that's the problem lol @thebusybee

Comment: If somebody on StackOverflow tells you how to do it, how would you then know whether it is true or not?

Comment: As I suggested, check for plausibility. Did you try the tool objdump or anything similar? It can print the contents of executable sections, including the code in hex. -- Additionally, I expect from the PE documentation that it explains the PE format in a way that leaves only very few open points, if any at all.

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat:* Don't know for sure, but the following is based on some [obvious] deductions ...

1. In `.text`, the `Pointer to Raw Data` value is `0x400`.
2. This [probably] isn't a valid *memory* address. So, it's [probably] a file *offset* (as this is what makes sense).
3. This is further supported by the fact that the `.text` section `Size of raw data` is `0x49a00`.
4. Now, `0x400 + 0x49a00` --> `0x49e00` which is the `Pointer to Raw Data` value of the *next* section `.rdata`

So, if you seek the PE file to `0x400` and read `0x49a00` bytes, you'll be getting the *contents* of the `.text` section [as you desire]. That length is the rounded up length [to align to the next section's data], so a better length to read might be the `ActualSize of code or data` value of `0x49937`

*Side note:* Although it's not a guarantee, the `0x400` *offset* of the `.text` section (the *first* section) *data* implies that the PE file header and all the [basic] section header structs fit in the first `0x400` (1024 decimal) bytes of the file. This is a reasonable assumption, given that PE is a simple format with a fixed number of section types (vs ELF that can have arbitrary/extensible sections).

Comment: thank you for answer. I tried this but it did not work properly. I read from 0x400 to 0x400+0x49937 but it just read 1307 characters.

Comment: @sadMarry the fact that you only read 1307 bytes tells me there is something wrong with your code, which you have not shown us.